# delete file from folder on click of button using php

Tags: php

When we run below code its not working. unlink function shows file name but not delete that file from folder

```
<?php
         $files = scandir("db-backup", 1);
         $path = "settings/db-backup/";
         echo '<table>';
         foreach ($files as $key => $value) 
         {
             if($value!='..' && $value!='.')
             {
                 $r =$path.$value;
            echo '<td>'.$value.'</td><td><input type="image" src="../../involve/images/icons/trash.png" value="Delete" onClick= "unlink('.$value.')"></td></tr>';
             }

         }
         echo '</table>';
        ?>
```

onclick of button it call unlink function it show unlink(filename) but not delete the file from folder

Comment: well, `unlink` in this case looks like a JS function, what does it look like and what code does it contain?

Comment: unlink is a php function and you are calling it like it is javascript function.

Comment: give me some suggestion to delete this file

Comment: echo '<td>'.$value.'</td><td><input type="image" src="../../involve/images/icons/trash.png" value="Delete" onClick= "'.unlink($value).'"></td></tr>'; when we replace our code still ot working

Comment: create a php file and use unlink function in that file to delete it from server and call that file using ajax. As simple as you would like.

Answer (score 2):

you can delete a file in php, only on server side. the way you are trying to delete, will never work.

Create a php file like `Deletefile.php` the write you delete logic in it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `unlink` in your URL as a GET variable, but you're not telling PHP to do anything with it like so:

```
unlink("filename.extension");
```